# Google and Facebook buttons

Tags: html, css, google-plus

Ok so I'v added the two like and plusOne buttons to my website and after that they just wont stay aligned no matter what I try.
I've tried adding some CSS code or something or anythnig but they just don't want to stay together. Sorry i have no code to give because it's all standard but i will give a screenshoot for you to see my problem.

[image]

EDIT:
Here's the code...

```
<div id="social-holder">

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.nslife.rs/profile.php?id=<?php echo $article_data_profile['id'];?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>

    <div style="margin-left: 10px;" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.naslife.rs/profile.php?id=<?php echo $article_data_profile['id']; ?>"data-type="button_count"></div>
    <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->

    <div class="g-plusone" data-href="http://www.nslife.rs/profile.php?id=<?php echo $article_data_profile['id']; ?>">
</div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#social-holder{
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: `Sorry i have no code to give because it's all standard`... Sorry what? What is standard?.. You need to provide code. How can we know what that is? Is it `div`s with `display: inline-block` Is it `<li>` with `float: left` and `display: inline`. Without code we are just guessing.... Provide code. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/tzaQE/) - There fixed.

Comment: I'v edited the question with the html code and css.

Comment: With the code you have given I see nothing wrong with it when using `display: inline-block` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/tzaQE/1/)

Comment: I've edited the code as Jay mentioned bellow. It works very well when separating everything in a specific class. i still needed some more fiddling but it's excellent now! Thank you for the support! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3V3ZC/)

#### HTML Code

```
    <div class="facebook_share">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-type="button_count"></div>    
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=556409774418683";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    </div>    
    <div class="twitter_share">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="way2tutorial" data-related="way2tutorial">Tweet</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
    </div>
    <div class="google_share">
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
          })();
        </script>
    </div>
```

#### CSS

```
div.facebook_share { 
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  /*margin-left: -17px;*/
  text-align: center; 
}
div.twitter_share { 
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center; 
}
div.google_share { 
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome i'm happy to help someone :)